# Is this guaranteed that CPU fetches memory in the opposite direction that stack grows?

Tags: assembly, stack

```
0x00000000004004b7 <func+31>:   mov    -0x18(%rbp),%rax
```

For an architecture whose stack grows to lower address, the above fetches `-0x18(%rbp)~-0x20(%rbp)`;And vice versa.

Is this true?

If that's the case,what's the technical reason?

Comment: Are you looking for an x86-specific answer? Because not all CPU's ahve a natural direction in which stacks grow.

Comment: That's why I say `vice verse`.There's no any assumption of stack grow direction.

Answer (score 3):

In general, the CPU has no knowledge of how the stack is implemented (that's usually up to the compiler).

So in your case, it will fetch a word starting at address `%rbp-0x18`.  If a word is 4 bytes, then it will fetch the word that spans { `%rbp-0x18`, `%rbp-0x17`, `%rbp-0x16`, `%rbp-0x15` }.

Comment: Do you imply that it has nothing to do with stack grow direction?

Comment: @Je Rog: Yes.  Well, I don't know the details of every single processor that's ever existed, but on all the ones that I can think of, a memory read/write/load/store instruction always specify the lowest address of the element.

Comment: Maybe that's because you never worked on cases where stack grows to higher address?

Comment: @Je Rog: Memory accesses are invariant of stack direction.  This is because the stack is not the only location that data exists.

Comment: On x86, the only instructions affected by stack grow direction are `push`, `pop` and various `call`s and `ret`s (which may include `int` and `iret`). The one you quote is a simple memory fetch that just happens to use rbp as a base register. The access is still sequential (towards bigger values of the address).

Answer (score 2):

No.  The things two are unrelated.  One is a property of the ISA, the other of the platform's ABI.

Incidentally, I do not know of any architecture on which multiple-byte accesses are not on ascending addresses.

Comment: ISA=compiler vendor here? Not sure the order of `one` and `the other` here.

Comment: ISA is Instruction Set Architecture, and is the name for the set of machine instructions available on a processor.

Comment: so you mean stack grow direction is of the platform's ABI?

Comment: @Je Rog: yes; the direction in which the stack grows is a property of the ABI.  Two OS's on the same hardware could have the stack grow in opposite directions, by having different ABIs.

Comment: Is there any reference,as this is different from @Oli Charlesworth's idea, `that's usually up to the compiler`

Comment: @Stephen: To be fair, the ISA usually has some notion of stack direction.  For instance, the x86 `push` instruction decrements the `esp` register.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: right, but one can still have an x86 ABI in which the stack grows up.  You just need to avoid using push/pop, and use separate adds to sp and stores instead.